# Deploying Eureka/ribbon code to Cloud Foundry

Tags: router, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I want to deploy Spring Cloud (Eureka/ribbon) code to Cloud Foundry.  Ribbon will do the client side load balancing, so I don't need the Cloud Foundry router.  How to I tell Cloud Foundry not to use its router?

Comment: It would be nice for one of the Pivotal Spring Cloud people comment on this.  It seems integral to using Ribbon on Pivotal Web Services.

Comment: Same here, I'd be highly interested in a yes/possible, or no/not possible answer from Pivotal, either from the Cloud Foundry team and/or from the Spring Cloud team. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did get it working on Pivotal Web Services.  I had to get them enable container to container communication for it to work.  See this link - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-networking.html

Comment: @Jim You may want to post an answer by yourself if you solved the problem. However, putting it in the question isn't a good solution, so I've removed it.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem